# Rolling Dice Probability

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, permutations, combinations, combinatory-logic

A fair dice is rolled 3 times,  The probability  of the product of the three outcomes  is a prime number is?

The products which give a prime number I found out to be only 4.

However for the total number of products,  I'm confused.

I know that I just can't use 216 as total as combinations such as 6×3×1=3×3×2=6×1×3  are counted not only twice but thrice!!

Also there are many products with such multiple countings.

So I what I am asking for is to a way to count the total possible products without any repitition.

Thanks.

Comment: There are $9$ products that give a prime, The natural sample space, as you wrote, has $216$ elements.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Shouldn't I count the total number of products as the sample space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to use the natural sample space of $6^3$ elements. That is because they are **equally likely**, which turns our problem into a straightforward counting problem.

If we use this sample space, there are precisely $9$ "favourables".

Comment: Finally  found  out the error in my reasoning all along.

Comment: Just as an extra,  can you please tell how to get the total possible products

Comment: @user307178: Counting the number of possible products is unpleasant.